# Why does template template parameters not work as expected?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors

```
#include <vector>

template
<
    typename T,
    typename Alloc,
    template<typename, typename> class Left
>
Left<T, Alloc>&&
operator <<(Left<T, Alloc>&& coll, T&& value)
{
    coll.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    return std::forward<Left<T, Alloc>>(coll);
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> c1;
    c1 << int(8);
}
```

VS 2015 outputs:

error C2678 : binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left - hand operand of type 'std::vector>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Why does template template parameters not work as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function takes an rvalue reference but you're passing an lvalue – `Left<T, Alloc>&&` is *not* a forwarding reference, so treating it as such with `std::forward` etc. is not correct. For now we'll disallow collection rvalues to simplify things:

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename Alloc,
    template<typename, typename> class Left
>
Left<T, Alloc>& operator <<(Left<T, Alloc>& coll, T&& value) {
    coll.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    return coll;
}
```

The above is one step closer, but [will not work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72873b5ffbcc4fe6) if passed an lvalue for `value`. One option is to force the correct argument for `Left`:

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename Alloc,
    template<typename, typename> class Left
>
Left<typename std::decay<T>::type, Alloc>&
operator <<(Left<typename std::decay<T>::type, Alloc>& coll, T&& value) {
    coll.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    return coll;
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d4d5a5ff8078b9b)</kbd>

This works, but doesn't leave us any easy way to support collection rvalues. The correct solution here IMO is to stop using template-templates and either `static_assert` that the container's `value_type` matches `T` or SFINAE the operator away if it doesn't:

```
template<typename Coll, typename T>
Coll& operator <<(Coll& coll, T&& value) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
            typename std::decay<T>::type,
            typename Coll::value_type
        >::value,
        "T does not match Coll::value_type"
    );
    coll.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    return coll;
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5913df874d2624f4)</kbd>

or

```
template<typename Coll, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
        typename std::decay<T>::type,
        typename Coll::value_type
    >::value,
    Coll&
>::type
operator <<(Coll& coll, T&& value) {
    coll.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    return coll;
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ded13929e8d293a9)</kbd>

With this done, now if you decide that you want to support collection rvalues after all, this is trivially done; to use the `static_assert` implementation as an example:

```
template<typename Coll, typename T>
Coll&& operator <<(Coll&& coll, T&& value) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
            typename std::decay<T>::type,
            typename std::decay<Coll>::type::value_type
        >::value,
        "T does not match Coll::value_type"
    );
    coll.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
    return std::forward<Coll>(coll);
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84781a6ad258784f)</kbd>

N.b. the above implementation only allows use of the operator with *exact matches* to `Coll::value_type`, but it is probably sensible to allow anything that can be *converted to* `Coll::value_type` – to implement this, just replace `std::is_same` with [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible).

Comment: Why is Left<...>&& not a forwarding reference? (Why isn't it considered a type deducing situation?)

Comment: @kfsone : The standard defines a forwarding reference to be "an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter"; a specialized template-template parameter is not the same as a template parameter. :-]

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I can see that being a common source of misunderstanding